# Building asynchronous `future` callback chain from compile-time dependency graph (DAG)

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, asynchronous, future

I have a compile-time [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of asynchronous tasks. The DAG shows the dependencies between the tasks: by analyzing it, it's possible to understand what tasks can run in parallel *(in separate threads)* and what tasks need to wait for other tasks to finish before they can begin *(dependencies*).

I want to generate a callback chain from the DAG, using `boost::future` and the `.then(...)`, `when_all(...)` continuation helper functions. The result of this generation will be a function that, when called, will start the callback chain and execute the tasks as described by the DAG, running as many tasks as possible in parallel.

I'm having trouble, however, finding a general algorithm that can work for all cases.

I made a few drawings to make the problem easier to understand. This is a legend that will show you what the symbols in the drawings mean:

[image: Legend: how to read the images.]

Let's begin with a simple, linear DAG:

[image: Example 0: linear DAG.]

This dependency graph consists of three tasks *(`A`, `B`, and `C`)*. `C` depends on `B`. `B` depends on `A`. There is no possibility of parallelism here - the generation algorithm would build something similar to this:

```
boost::future<void> A, B, C, end;

A.then([]
    {
        B.then([]
            {
                C.get();
                end.get();
            });
    });
```

*(Note that all code samples are not 100% valid - I'm ignoring move semantics, forwarding and lambda captures.)*

There are many approaches to solve this linear DAG: either by starting from the end or the beginning, it's trivial to build a correct callback chain.

Things start to get more complicated when [forks and joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model) are introduced.

Here's a DAG with a fork/join:

[image: Example 1: DAG with a fork/join.]

It's difficult to think of a callback chain that matches this DAG. If I try to work backwards, starting from the end, my reasoning is as follows:

- `end` depends on `B` and `D`. *(join)*

  - `D` depends on `C`.
  - `B` and `C` depend on `A`. *(fork)*

A possible chain looks something like this:

```
boost::future<void> A, B, C, D, end;

A.then([]
    {
        boost::when_all(B, C.then([]
                               {
                                   D.get();
                               }))
            .then([]
                {
                    end.get();
                });
    });
```

I found it difficult to write this chain by hand, and I'm also doubtful about its correctness. I could not think of a general way to implement an algorithm that could generate this - additional difficulties are also present due to the fact that `when_all` needs its arguments to be moved into it.

Let's see one last, even more complex, example:

[image: Example 2: complex DAG.]

Here we want to exploit parallelism as much as possible. Consider task `E`: `E` can be run in parallel with any of `[B, C, D]`.

This is a possible callback chain:

```
boost::future<void> A, B, C, D, E, F, end;

A.then([]
    {
        boost::when_all(boost::when_all(B, C).then([]
                            {
                                D.get();
                            }),
            E)
            .then([]
                {
                    F.then([]
                        {
                            end.get();
                        });
                });
    });
```

I've tried to come up with a general algorithm in several ways:

- Starting from the beginning of the DAG, trying to build up the chain using `.then(...)` continuations. This doesn't work with joins, as the target join task would is repeated multiple times.
- Starting from the end of the DAG, trying to generate the chain using `when_all(...)` continuations. This fails with forks, as the node that creates the fork is repeated multiple times.

Obviously the "breadth-first traversal" approach doesn't work well here. From the code samples that I have hand-written, it seems that the algorithm needs to be aware of forks and joins, and needs to be able to correctly mix `.then(...)` and `when_all(...)` continuations.

Here are my final questions:

- **Is it always possible to generate a `future`-based callback chain from a DAG of task dependencies, where every task appears only once in the callback chain?**
- **If so, how can a general algorithm that, given a task dependency DAG builds a callback chain, be implemented?**

---

EDIT 1:

[Here's an additional approach](http://vittorioromeo.info/Misc/dag_task_idea.pdf) I'm trying to explore.

The idea is to generate a `([dependencies...] -> [dependents...])` map data structure from the DAG, and to generate the callback chain from that map.

If `len(dependencies...) > 1`, then `value` is a *join* node.

If `len(dependents...) > 1`, then `key` is a *fork* node.

All the key-value pairs in the map can be expressed as `when_all(keys...).then(values...)` continuations.

The difficult part is figuring out the correct order in which to "expand" *(think about something similar to a parser)* the nodes and how to connect the fork/join continuations together.

Consider the following map, generated by image [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMxYl.png).

```
depenendencies  |  dependents
----------------|-------------
[F]             :  [end]
[D, E]          :  [F]
[B, C]          :  [D]
[A]             :  [E, C, B]
[begin]         :  [A]
```

By applying some sort of parser-like reductions/passes, we can get a "clean" callback chain:

```
// First pass:
// Convert everything to `when_all(...).then(...)` notation
when_all(F).then(end)
when_all(D, E).then(F)
when_all(B, C).then(D)
when_all(A).then(E, C, B)
when_all(begin).then(A)

// Second pass:
// Solve linear (trivial) transformations
when_all(D, E).then(
    when_all(F).then(end)
)
when_all(B, C).then(D)
when_all(
    when_all(begin).then(A)
).then(E, C, B)

// Third pass:
// Solve fork/join transformations
when_all(
    when_all(begin).then(A)
).then(
    when_all(
        E, 
        when_all(B, C).then(D)
    ).then(
        when_all(F).then(end)
    )   
)
```

The third pass is the most important one, but also the one that looks really difficult to design an algorithm for.

Notice how `[B, C]` have to be found inside the `[E, C, B]` list, and how, in the `[D, E]` dependency list, `D` must be interpreted as the result of `when_all(B, C).then(D)` and chained together with `E` in `when_all(E, when_all(B, C).then(D))`.

Maybe the entire problem can be simplified as:

**Given a map consisting of `[dependencies...] -> [dependents...]` key value pairs, how could an algorithm that transforms those pairs to a `when_all(...)`/`.then(...)` continuation chain be implemented?**

EDIT 2:

Here's some [pseudocode](http://pastebin.com/wRJpUr4b) I came up with for the approach described above. It seems to work for the DAG I tried, but I need to spend more time on it and "mentally" test it with other, trickier, DAG configurations.

Comment: Why do you want to complicate your life by having to come up with such a chain, instead of queuing executable tasks in a thread pool? That's trivial and should be just as performant. Or if you don't want them executed in parallel, just make it a normal queue.

Comment: @Voo: I will use a thread pool, after I create the chain. I need the chain because tasks may depend on other tasks, and I have to respect those dependencies while trying to be "as parallel as possible". If I were to enqueue the tasks while using something like a breadth-first traversal, I could miss opportunities to parallelize independent tasks.

Comment: Actually you only need a list of tasks that depend on a tasks and a counter  as far as I can see - I'll post a solution when I'm home.

Comment: All your pseucode just involves `future`. Presumably the point of the exercise is actually to have `task`s being run in certain threads? It's unclear what the point of your `when_all/then` chains are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @Barry: given a compile-time DAG of some tasks, the goal is to build a future chain that runs all the tasks, respecting their dependencies. The built chain can then be executed to fire off all the tasks. Using a future chain with when_all/then continuations will make sure that all tasks that can run in parallel do so, and that all tasks that depend on another task won't run until that task is completed.

Comment: Right but your examples all are just waiting on futures. Who's running the tasks, in what threads, how?

Comment: I see what you mean *(I don't think it's in the scope of the question, though)* - the examples are incomplete and not correct. Every task would call it's own dependent children as soon as it has finished its execution. Ideally I would execute the tasks in a thread pool.

Comment: Is using boost::future a requirement? I would like to present an answer without using it but I am not sure weather or not it is a requirement at this point.

Comment: I am not sure that the callback chain you present are well-formed code. For instance, a precondition to `when_all` is that all the input futures are valid. Maybe you need something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a5d037b49de7ba0)?

Comment: @TimHallyburton: using it is my current plan, but if you have something better/alternative to suggest please go ahead :)

Comment: @sbabbi: Here's a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83a6617b30bcf351) of one of my "desired" callback chains.

Comment: @sbabbi: Compiling the previous example on my system had different results. I've [fixed the example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/374888fa7aaeffde) by adding get() calls where required.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Well I see your point now. My answer does not really answer this question, but I am still of the opinion that if you know the graph at compile time, having the main thread build the chain is an easier solution. You should only need a single call to `async`, the one that spawns the first node. All the subsequent tasks can inherit the launch policy from their parent future. In this way you can also easily use a thread pool executor to limit the number of concurrent tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If redundant dependencies may occur, remove them first (see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33638/remove-redundant-dependencies-from-a-directed-acyclic-graph).

Then perform the following graph transformations (building sub-expressions in merged nodes) until you are down to a single node (in a way similar to how you'd calculate a network of resistors):

[image: Graph transformations]

`*`: Additional incoming or outgoing dependencies, depending on placement

`(...)`: Expression in a single node

Java code including setup for your more complex example:

```
public class DirectedGraph {
  /** Set of all nodes in the graph */
  static Set<Node> allNodes = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  static class Node {
    /** Set of all preceeding nodes */
    Set<Node> prev = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    /** Set of all following nodes */
    Set<Node> next = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    String value;

    Node(String value) {
      this.value = value;
      allNodes.add(this);
    }

    void addPrev(Node other) {
      prev.add(other);
      other.next.add(this);
    }

    /** Returns one of the next nodes */
    Node anyNext() {
      return next.iterator().next();
    }

    /** Merges this node with other, then removes other */
    void merge(Node other) {
      prev.addAll(other.prev);
      next.addAll(other.next);
      for (Node on: other.next) {
        on.prev.remove(other);
        on.prev.add(this);
      }
      for (Node op: other.prev) {
        op.next.remove(other);
        op.next.add(this);
      }
      prev.remove(this);
      next.remove(this);
      allNodes.remove(other);
    }

    public String toString() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  /** 
   * Merges sequential or parallel nodes following the given node.
   * Returns true if any node was merged.
   */
  public static boolean processNode(Node node) {
    // Check if we are the start of a sequence. Merge if so.
    if (node.next.size() == 1 && node.anyNext().prev.size() == 1) {
      Node then = node.anyNext();
      node.value += " then " + then.value;
      node.merge(then);
      return true;
    }

    // See if any of the next nodes has a parallel node with
    // the same one level indirect target. 
    for (Node next : node.next) {

      // Nodes must have only one in and out connection to be merged.
      if (next.prev.size() == 1 && next.next.size() == 1) {

        // Collect all parallel nodes with only one in and out connection 
        // and the same target; the same source is implied by iterating over 
        // node.next again.
        Node target = next.anyNext().next();
        Set<Node> parallel = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();
        for (Node other: node.next) {
          if (other != next && other.prev.size() == 1
             && other.next.size() == 1 && other.anyNext() == target) {
            parallel.add(other);
          }
        }

        // If we have found any "parallel" nodes, merge them
        if (parallel.size() > 0) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("allNodes(");
          sb.append(next.value);
          for (Node other: parallel) {
            sb.append(", ").append(other.value);
            next.merge(other);
          }
          sb.append(")");
          next.value = sb.toString();
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node a = new Node("A");
    Node b = new Node("B");
    Node c = new Node("C");
    Node d = new Node("D");
    Node e = new Node("E");
    Node f = new Node("F");

    f.addPrev(d);
    f.addPrev(e);

    e.addPrev(a);

    d.addPrev(b);
    d.addPrev(c);

    b.addPrev(a);
    c.addPrev(a);

    boolean anyChange;
    do {
      anyChange = false;
      for (Node node: allNodes) {
        if (processNode(node)) {
          anyChange = true;
          // We need to leave the inner loop here because changes
          // invalidate the for iteration. 
          break;
        }
      }
      // We are done if we can't find any node to merge.
    } while (anyChange);

    System.out.println(allNodes.toString());
  }
}
```

Output: `A then all(E, all(B, C) then D) then F`

Comment: This answer looks very promising due to its simplicity - however I feel that some comments in the code would help readability. Here are my assumptions *(that I would like some comments in the code to clarify)*: the `inverse` set of `X` contains all nodes that depend on `X`. `node.inverse.size() == 1` means that the outgoing connection is linear *(neither a fork nor a join)*. `node.dependsOn.size() == 1` means that the incoming connection is linear. `merge` is used to merge all the nodes spawned by a fork together, and allows the algorithm to work with nested forks/joins.

Comment: The part of the code that I think requires some comments: the loop inside `processNode` starting with `for(Node next : node.inverse)` *(the conditions inside the `if` statements can get hard to follow - extracting them to more readable methods or adding comments can help)*.

Comment: I have renamed `inverse` to `next` and `dependsOn` to `prev` -- I think that makes it easier to "connect" the implementation to the graph. I have factored out `next.iterator().next()` to a method named `anyNext()` to make clearer that this just returns a single node from the set (which is of size one where we use this). I have also added some comments to processNode and made more explicit that we run until no more merge opportunities were found. The reason for leaving the loops early is that the iterators become invalid after changes to the underlying set.

Comment: The best documentation is probably the drawing though :)

Comment: [Here's a C++ implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/736cfdb6e7ebca8e) with an example graph with multiple forks/joins. The algorithm produces the desired result. The hard part is now converting it to a compile-time algorithm :)

Comment: Sorry, I've got a question. I'm probably misunderstanding, but does this work with the DAG "{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, f}, {c, g}, {d, e}, {d, g}, {e, h}, {f, h}, {g, h}}"? It seems to me that there's no way to describe this DAG in `then`/`all` notation while maintaining maximum parallelization. The algorithm in this answer doesn't compile as is, so I tried to fix it (I hope I didn't make an error) and I got `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]` for this graph when `a then all(b,c,d) then all(e,f,g) then h` seems to be always at least as fast. Am I understanding right? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to start from the *entry* node of the graph, as if you were writing the code by hand. In order to solve the `join` problem, you can not use a recursive solution, you need to have a [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of your graph, and *then* build the graph according to the ordering.

This gives the guarantee that when you build a node all of its predecessors have already been created.

To achieve this goal we can use a DFS, with [reverse postordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings).

Once you have a topological sorting, you can forget the original node IDs, and refer to nodes with their number in the list. In order to do that you need create a compile time map that allows to retrieve the node predecessors using the node index in the topological sorting instead of the node original node index.

---

**EDIT**: Following up on how to implement topological sorting at compile time, I refactored this answer.

To be on the same page I will assume that your graph looks like this:

```
struct mygraph
{
     template<int Id>
     static constexpr auto successors(node_id<Id>) ->
        list< node_id<> ... >; //List of successors for the input node

     template<int Id>
     static constexpr auto predecessors(node_id<Id>) ->
        list< node_id<> ... >; //List of predecessors for the input node

     //Get the task associated with the given node.
     template<int Id>
     static constexpr auto task(node_id<Id>);

     using entry_node = node_id<0>;
};
```

### Step 1: topological sort

The basic ingredient that you need is a compile time set of node-ids. In TMP a set is also a list, simply because in `set<Ids...>` the order of the `Ids` matters. This means that you can use the same data structure to encode the information on whether a node as been visited AND the resulting ordering at the same time.

```
/** Topological sort using DFS with reverse-postordering **/
template<class Graph>
struct topological_sort
{
private:
    struct visit;

    // If we reach a node that we already visited, do nothing.
    template<int Id, int ... Is>
    static constexpr auto visit_impl( node_id<Id>,
                                      set<Is...> visited,
                                      std::true_type )
    {
        return visited;
    }

    // This overload kicks in when node has not been visited yet.
    template<int Id, int ... Is>
    static constexpr auto visit_impl( node_id<Id> node,
                                      set<Is...> visited,
                                      std::false_type )
    {
        // Get the list of successors for the current node
        constexpr auto succ = Graph::successors(node);

        // Reverse postordering: we call insert *after* visiting the successors
        // This will call "visit" on each successor, updating the
        // visited set after each step.
        // Then we insert the current node in the set.
        // Notice that if the graph is cyclic we end up in an infinite
        // recursion here.
        return fold( succ,
                     visited,
                     visit() ).insert(node);

        // Conventional DFS would be:
        // return fold( succ, visited.insert(node), visit() );
    }

    struct visit
    {
        // Dispatch to visit_impl depending on the result of visited.contains(node)
        // Note that "contains" returns a type convertible to
        // integral_constant<bool,x>
        template<int Id, int ... Is>
        constexpr auto operator()( set<Is...> visited, node_id<Id> node ) const
        {
            return visit_impl(node, visited, visited.contains(node) );
        }
    };

public:
    template<int StartNodeId>
    static constexpr auto compute( node_id<StartNodeId> node )
    {
        // Start visiting from the entry node
        // The set of visited nodes is initially empty.
        // "as_list" converts set<Is ... > to list< node_id<Is> ... >.
        return reverse( visit()( set<>{}, node ).as_list() );
    }
};
```

This algorithm with the graph from your last example (assuming `A = node_id<0>`, `B = node_id<1>`, etc.), produces `list<A,B,C,D,E,F>`.

### Step 2: graph map

This is simply an adapter that modifies the Id of each node in your graph according to a given ordering. So assuming that previous steps returned `list<C,D,A,B>`, this `graph_map` would map the index 0 to `C`, index 1 to `D`, etc.

```
template<class Graph, class List>
class graph_map
{   
    // Convert a node_id from underlying graph.
    // Use a function-object so that it can be passed to algorithms.
    struct from_underlying
    { 
        template<int I>
        constexpr auto operator()(node_id<I> id) 
        { return node_id< find(id, List{}) >{}; }
    };

    struct to_underlying
    { 
        template<int I>
        constexpr auto operator()(node_id<I> id) 
        { return get<I>(List{}); }
    };

public:        
    template<int Id>
    static constexpr auto successors( node_id<Id> id )
    {
        constexpr auto orig_id = to_underlying()(id);
        constexpr auto orig_succ = Graph::successors( orig_id );
        return transform( orig_succ, from_underlying() );
    }

    template<int Id>
    static constexpr auto predecessors( node_id<Id> id )
    {
        constexpr auto orig_id = to_underlying()(id);
        constexpr auto orig_succ = Graph::predecessors( orig_id );
        return transform( orig_succ, from_underlying() );
    }

    template<int Id>
    static constexpr auto task( node_id<Id> id )
    {
        return Graph::task( to_underlying()(id) );
    }

    using entry_node = decltype( from_underlying()( typename Graph::entry_node{} ) );
};
```

### Step 3: assemble the result

We can now iterate over each node id in order. Thanks to the way we built the graph map, we know that all the predecessors of `I` have a node id which is less than `I`, for every possible node `I`.

```
// Returns a tuple<> of futures
template<class GraphMap, class ... Ts>
auto make_cont( std::tuple< future<Ts> ... > && pred )
{
     // The next node to work with is N:
     constexpr auto current_node = node_id< sizeof ... (Ts) >();

     // Get a list of all the predecessors for the current node.
     auto indices = GraphMap::predecessors( current_node );

     // "select" is some magic function that takes a tuple of Ts
     // and an index_sequence, and returns a tuple of references to the elements 
     // from the input tuple that are in the indices list. 
     auto futures = select( pred, indices );

     // Assuming you have an overload of when_all that takes a tuple,
     // otherwise use C++17 apply.
     auto join = when_all( futures );

     // Note: when_all with an empty parameter list returns a future< tuple<> >,
     // which is always ready.
     // In general this has to be a shared_future, but you can avoid that
     // by checking if this node has only one successor.
     auto next = join.then( GraphMap::task( current_node ) ).share();

     // Return a new tuple of futures, pushing the new future at the back.
     return std::tuple_cat( std::move(pred),
                            std::make_tuple(std::move(next)) );         
}


// Returns a tuple of futures, you can take the last element if you
// know that your DAG has only one leaf, or do some additional 
// processing to extract only the leaf nodes.
template<class Graph>
auto make_callback_chain()
{
    constexpr auto entry_node = typename Graph::entry_node{};

    constexpr auto sorted_list = 
         topological_sort<Graph>::compute( entry_node );

    using map = graph_map< Graph, decltype(sorted_list) >;

    // Note: we are not really using the "index" in the functor here, 
    // we only want to call make_cont once for each node in the graph
    return fold( sorted_list, 
                 std::make_tuple(), //Start with an empty tuple
                 []( auto && tuple, auto index )
                 {
                     return make_cont<map>(std::move(tuple));
                 } );
}
```

[Full live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1169f6abb41918cf)

Comment: How can a depth-first-search return `FEDCBA` starting from the entry node? (Assuming [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rMxYl.png) is the graph in question). Possible DFSs starting from the entry node could be `ABDFCE` or `AEFCDB`.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo
Use [reverse postordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). In any case what you want is a topological sort of your graph, dfs is the easiest way to do it in TMP.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited your answer to make it obvious.

Comment: If you feel it is needed, I can expand on how to get the topological sort at compile time. How do your node handles look like? Can they be represented as template parameters?

Comment: It would definitely help. My graph is represented as a compile-time adjacency list, using a compile-time map. The keys of the map are `node_id`, the values are compile-time lists `list<node_id>`. A `node_id` is an `integral_constant<int, x>`. Data can be added to nodes and/or edges by creating additional compile-time maps that map the node ids to the data.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00ca3287c263fe28) is a demo. I'll expand my answer later today after work.

Comment: A topological sort is suboptimal, no? There may be 2 tasks that can be performed asynchronously (tasks B, C in your "complex example" after task A is finished) that would not be revealed by a top. sort. All you need is in_edges for every node to set up the dependencies, not a full top. sort. How would a top sort allow for 2 tasks to be run asynchronously at the same time?

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian  The task are still executed asynchronously. This is the job of `boost::future`. Our job here is just to setup the `.then`/`when_all` chain. And you *do* need a topological sort to do that, simply because you can not pass an uninitialized future to `when_all`

Comment: Really good answer, especially after the updates. The full code example and the comments really help a lot. I also like your hana-like metaprogramming style. One thing I am not convinced about is the use of `shared_future`: as far as I understand, you're using it to allow nodes spawned by forks to read the data produced by the parent. Assuming that the data produced by a parent node will only be read by its children, wouldn't it be possible *(and more efficient)*  to cache its result in a variable and pass it to the children tasks?

Comment: I am asking this because in my project all the tasks will return `void` and the POD they produce/modify will live in a shared memory location. The configuration of the DAG will make sure that two tasks never write to the same memory location in parallel. I also was under the impression that building a callback-chain with `when_all` and `then` would not require the use of `shared_future`, because "every task would appear only once" in the chain, but maybe I'm incorrect. Here's an [use case example](http://pastie.org/10753796) of why I think that shared futures could be avoided.

Comment: Sorry I agree with @Voo that all we need are dependencies, or in_edges() for each node. Execution of all tasks with 0 dependencies starts the process, and the rest fall like a domino chain as they are waiting/blocking on completion of their dependencies. My example below shows how the graph can be set up, at instantiation of the scheduler, using C++11/14 futures. I think it can be made compile-time with a bit of work.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yep I am not persuaded by the `shared_future`. They were not present in the first version of my answer. The reason why I think you need it is that `when_all` *eats* its arguments. I.e. `All input futures valid() == false` is a postcondition for `when_all`. In your last example if you call `B = when_all(A)` A is no longer valid, thus the subsequent call to `C = when_all(A)` would be ill-formed. (In general there are multiple predecessors to B and C, but none of your examples show this case).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Also I just learned two facts, at least with the version of `boost.threads` available on coliru: 1) after calling `A.then`, A is invalid. 2) you need to move the future into `when_all`.
So yeah, you probably need `shared_future` most of the times.

Comment: Here's a [callback chain example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/374888fa7aaeffde) that does not use shared futures.

Answer (score 2):

This seems reasonably easy if you stop thinking about it in form of explicit dependencies and organizing a DAG. Every task can be organized in something like the following (C# because it's so much simpler to explain the idea):

```
class MyTask
{
    // a list of all tasks that depend on this to be finished
    private readonly ICollection<MyTask> _dependenants;
    // number of not finished dependencies of this task
    private int _nrDependencies;

    public int NrDependencies
    {
        get { return _nrDependencies; }
        private set { _nrDependencies = value; }
    }
}
```

If you have a organized your DAG in such a form, the problem is actually really simple: Every Task where `_nrDependencies == 0` can be executed. So we need a run method that looks something like the following:

```
public async Task RunTask()
{
    // Execute actual code of the task.
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var dependent in _dependenants)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref dependent._nrDependencies) == 0)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => dependent.RunTask()));
        }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Basically as soon as our task finished, we go through all our dependents and execute all of those that have no more unfinished dependencies.

To start the whole thing off the only thing you have to do is to call `RunTask()` for all tasks that have zero dependents to start with (at least one of those must exist since we have a DAG). As soon as all of these tasks have finished, we know that the whole DAG has been executed.

Comment: This solution is indeed much simpler, and worked properly in my experiments. Unfortunately I am not satisfied with it, because it doesn't exploit the fact that the dependencies between tasks are known at compile-time, and uses atomic checks/decrements at runtime to respect the dependencies. Generating a chain of continuations, while much harder in its implementation, would theoretically allow the compiler to avoid those runtime checks. [Example of what I mean.](http://pastie.org/10747936)

Comment: @vittorio it's true that there's some overhead, but if you're doing that little work in your tasks that the few lost clock cycles are measurable, concurrency seems unlikely to help with performance - even in the best case. Also you could usr a single threaded implementation with a queue to compute an optimal solution I think

Comment: @Voo this is more or less how `when_all` and friends is actually implemented.

Comment: More to the point unbounded parallelism is typically inefficient and the key to performance is careful scheduling of CPU and I/O-bound tasks so as not to overwhelm the system and degrade the net performance, and creating an execution plan based on this data. Something which typically requires domain knowledge or profile-guided scheduling to get right.

Answer (score 2):

This graph is not constructed in compile-time, but it is not clear to me if that is a requirement. The graph is held in a boost graph implemented as `adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS>`. A single dispatch will start the tasks. We just need the in-edges at each node, so that we know just what we are waiting on. That pre-calculated at instantiation in the scheduler below.

I contend that a full topological sort is not needed.

For example, if the dependency graph were:

[image]

use `scheduler_driver.cpp`

For a join as in

[image]

just redefine the `Graph` to define the directed edges.

So, to answer your 2 questions:

. Yes, for a DAG. Only unique immediate dependencies are needed for each node, which can be pre-computed as below. The dependency chain can then be initiated with a single dispatch, and the domino chain falls.

. Yes, see algorithm below (using C++11 threads, not `boost::thread`). For forks, a `shared_future` is required for the communication, while joins are supported with `future`-based communication.

scheduler_driver.hpp:

```
#ifndef __SCHEDULER_DRIVER_HPP__
#define __SCHEDULER_DRIVER_HPP__

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#include "scheduler.h"

#endif
```

scheduler_driver.cpp:

```
#include "scheduler_driver.hpp"

enum task_nodes
  {
    task_0,
    task_1,
    task_2,
    task_3,
    task_4,
    task_5,
    task_6,
    task_7,
    task_8,
    task_9,
    N
  };

int basic_task(int a, int d)
{
  std::chrono::milliseconds sleepDuration(d);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleepDuration);
  std::cout << "Result: " << a << "\n";
  return a;
}

using namespace SCHEDULER;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  using F = std::function<R()>;

  Graph deps(N);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_1, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_2, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_3, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_4, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_5, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_6, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_7, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_8, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_9, deps);

  std::vector<F> tasks = 
    {
      std::bind(basic_task, 0, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 1, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 2, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 3, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 4, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 5, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 6, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 7, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 8, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 9, 1000)
    };

  auto s = std::make_unique<scheduler<int>>(std::move(deps), std::move(tasks));
  s->doit();

  return 0;
}
```

scheduler.h:

```
#ifndef __SCHEDULER2_H__
#define __SCHEDULER2_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>

using namespace boost;

namespace SCHEDULER
{

  using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS>;
  using Edge = graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;
  using Vertex = graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
  using VectexCont = std::vector<Vertex>;
  using outIt = graph_traits<Graph>::out_edge_iterator;
  using inIt = graph_traits<Graph>::in_edge_iterator;

  template<typename R>
    class scheduler
    {
    public:
      using ret_type = R;
      using fun_type = std::function<R()>;
      using prom_type = std::promise<ret_type>;
      using fut_type = std::shared_future<ret_type>;

      scheduler() = default;
      scheduler(const Graph &deps_, const std::vector<fun_type> &tasks_) :
        g(deps_),
        tasks(tasks_) { init_();}
        scheduler(Graph&& deps_, std::vector<fun_type>&& tasks_) :
          g(std::move(deps_)),
          tasks(std::move(tasks_)) { init_(); }
        scheduler(const scheduler&) = delete;
        scheduler& operator=(const scheduler&) = delete;

        void doit();

    private:
        void init_();
        std::list<Vertex> get_sources(const Vertex& v);
        auto task_thread(fun_type&& f, int i);

        Graph g;
        std::vector<fun_type> tasks;
        std::vector<prom_type> prom;
        std::vector<fut_type> fut;
        std::vector<std::thread> th;
        std::vector<std::list<Vertex>> sources;

    };

  template<typename R>
    void
    scheduler<R>::init_()
    {
      int num_tasks = tasks.size();

      prom.resize(num_tasks);
      fut.resize(num_tasks);

      // Get the futures
      for(size_t i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          fut[i] = prom[i].get_future();
        }

      // Predetermine in_edges for faster traversal
      sources.resize(num_tasks);
      for(size_t i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          sources[i] = get_sources(i);
        }
    }

  template<typename R>
    std::list<Vertex>
    scheduler<R>::get_sources(const Vertex& v)
    {
      std::list<Vertex> r;
      Vertex v1;
      inIt j, j_end;
      boost::tie(j,j_end) = in_edges(v, g);
      for(;j != j_end;++j)
        {
          v1 = source(*j, g);
          r.push_back(v1);
        }
      return r;
    }

  template<typename R>
    auto
    scheduler<R>::task_thread(fun_type&& f, int i)
    {
      auto j_beg = sources[i].begin(), 
        j_end = sources[i].end();
      for(;
          j_beg != j_end;
          ++j_beg)
        {
          R val = fut[*j_beg].get();
        }

      return std::thread([this](fun_type f, int i)
                         {
                           prom[i].set_value(f());
                         },f,i);
    }

  template<typename R>
    void
    scheduler<R>::doit()
    {
      size_t num_tasks = tasks.size();
      th.resize(num_tasks);

      for(int i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          th[i] = task_thread(std::move(tasks[i]), i);
        }
      for_each(th.begin(), th.end(), mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    }

} // namespace SCHEDULER

#endif
```

Comment: The fact that the graph is at run-time is not an issue. I will analyze your code when I get back home as it is not obvious to me what it is doing. Just to be sure - does your algorithm handle joins correctly? Your example DAG has only forks.

Comment: Join in this context corresponds to >= 2 dependencies (parents) for one task. Yes it is easy to set up such an example. with 4 nodes. I am using C++11/14 futures - shared_futures actually for the forks.

Comment: There is now a join example above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Intel's [TBB Flow Graph](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-flow-graph) library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your setup is and why you need to build DAG, but I think that simple greedy algorithm *may* suffice.

```
when (some task have finished) {
     mark output resources done;
     find all tasks that can be run;
     post them to thread pool;
}
```